# Javascript ReferenceError: Can't find variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PO845191

```
<a class="dropdown-item" class="btn-group btn-group-xs" ><button class="btn btn-link"  onClick="underReviewPo('.$row->po_id.')">Convert To Under Review</button>
```

My javascript won't work , it show this error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PO845191 "
But if I use an int there is no error occurred .

Here is for Ajax :

```
function requestBuyerSign(poID) {   
        swal({
              title: "Request Signature",
              text: "Confirm To Request Signature To Buyer",
              icon: "success",
              buttons: true,
              dangerMode: false,
            }).then((willConvert) => {
          if (willConvert) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?= base_url() ?>PurchaseOrder/request_buyer_signature/"+poID,
                type:"POST",
                data:{poID:poID},
                success:function(data){
                    if(data=='success'){
                        swal("Request Has Been Sent",{
                            icon:'success',
                    });
                    }else{
                        swal("Error Occured",{
                            icon:"error"
                    });

                    }
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    incomplete.ajax.reload();
                    pofr.ajax.reload();
                }
            });
          } 
        });
        }
```

Comment: You aren't quoting your string, so javascript thinks it's a variable

Comment: In general, a better way is to use something like `extract($row);` and `echo "<a data-id='$po_id' ... >";`, then assign click handlers using JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks ! Already solved it